# Jquery generate automatic hyphen while type US mobile number on input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I am using jquery validator plugin when i type us code on my page i need to generate hyphen automatically after 3 digit, the jquery code that I am currently using is and it allow only when use enter mobile number in this format(000-000-0000)

```
customphone: function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(value);
},
```

But the problem is i manually type the hyphen but and i want to generate that hyphen automatically....Could anyone please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You can try [input mask plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Just you need to use,

```
<input data-inputmask="'mask': '999-999-999'">
```

[Demo Page](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/)

Comment: yeah thank you but how can i access this using jquery validator plugin

Comment: This plugin doesn't allow to write anything else instead of the pattern, and it has status like `valid` from which you can get the value is valid or not.